# Linux Network UPS Tools Setup

Tags: ups, linux-server

Power failures have been wrecking my server, so I recently plugged it into a USB UPS.

The problem is that the power failures last longer than the UPS battery can handle so I need the server to shutdown when the UPS battery is low.

I have been looking into the Network UPS Tools software and it seems to be exactly what I need although I find the documentation to be very unhelpful and difficult to follow.

Has anyone had success in installing it and if so; what are the most important steps to ensure a basic shutdown command on low UPS power?

Comment: One really important step is to make sure you've got some sort of data connection to the UPS.  Some UPSs might not even support this.  Some actually support this only if you purchase a specialized add-on card that fits into the UPS.  Do you have an Ethernet cable, or a USB cable, or a serial cable (connected to an old-school serial port), or anything like that connected to the UPS?

Comment: The UPS has the data USB cable (similar to the one's printers use). I did a trial with Winpower and it is receiving signal from the UPS. I did not like Winpower so I would like to give NUT a shot